# SyntaxError in UsersController#create -- @user.save Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I'm new to RoR and am experimenting after completing the rails for zombies course by trying to make a running version on my own. I am currently following this tutorial (http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch) to try and make an authentication system from scratch. I know it is done in rails 3 so I have had some fun changing some things to rails 4 friendly.

However, when trying to create a user I get the error "SyntaxError in UsersController#create" pointing to line 8 of my UsersController (if @user.save)

** EDIT ** /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:377: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')'

The error is saying expecting a ')' but I had an '=' sign

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
   @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed up!"
    else 
      render "new"
    end 
  end   

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password, :salt, :encrypted_password)
  end    
end


class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :password
  validates_presence_of :password, :on =>create # needed to move line up from below to. Cannot encrypt password without validating password
  before_save :encrypt_password

  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validates_presence_of :email
  validates_uniqueness_of :email

  def encrypt_password
      if password.present?
          self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
          self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
      end
  end   
end
```

Comment: Is `:on =>create` in your model just a copy'n'paste error or is it really like that?

Comment: :on =>create is the model. needed to move it up to before the :encrypt_password method because I was getting an error.

Comment: Try removing `attr_accessor :password` from your `User` class...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you certain that the problem isn't really inside your `User` model? This:

```
validates_presence_of :password, :on =>create
```

is syntactically valid but it doesn't make any sense. You do have a `create` class method so

```
:on => create
```

is fine as far as Ruby is concerned but I doubt `validates_presence_of`'s `:on` option knows what to do with what `User.create` will return. There could be something going on inside `validates_presence_of` that is trying to treat the `:on` value as a method name or similar, that sort of thing could easily trigger your confusing and strange looking error from inside `active_support/callbacks.rb`. Once you start using [`instance_eval`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval), [`module_eval`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-module_eval), and friends, your error messages suddenly stop making sense and Rails makes heavy use of such things.

Your validation should look like this:

```
:on => :create
# or
on: :create
```

so fix that first and see what happens.

Comment: When I make that change I now get an error when I click to my sign up page. Here is a link to my git repo if that helps: https://github.com/BrianLobdell/zombietwitter

Comment: A copy of the error message with this correction: /Users/brianlobdell/Desktop/zombietwitter/app/models/user.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end on: :create # needed to move lin... ^          The user.save is listed under "extended source"

Comment: I'm using ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]

Comment: You're supposed to use `validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create`. I thought the context was clear.

Comment: Ahh my mistake. That solved that error message, but now I'm receiving one with respect to NameError in UsersController#create
uninitialized constant User::BCrypt  Really appreciate your help so far, mate

Comment: Have you tried reading [the bcrypt docs](https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby)?

Comment: I couldn't find anything in the bcrypt docs, but I did find a solution that instructed me to add :require => 'bcrypt' after the gem installation. Originally my file read gem 'bcrypt-ruby', ~=> xxxx. it now reads gem 'bcrypt-ruby', :require => 'bcrypt'. This worked but I have no idea why it worked.

Comment: `:require => 'bcrypt'` is more or less like a `require 'bcrypt'` in all your files. The docs tell you to `require 'bcrypt'` in places that needed it.